# Multiple IP address in one connection string C# Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, connection

I have an application with C#, Entity Framework and SQL Server. Since I have two service providers, our database server has two public IPs (one for each provider) with only one will be active at a time.

Is there a way I can mention multiple servers in connection string of my `web.config` file provided they are having same credentials?

In case if my one server goes down or any thing happens wrong it can automatically switch to another server. I have used the below connection string but only xxx.xx.xx.xx server is working, when the IP changes database not connected.

```
<add name="UserManagementEntities" 
     connectionString="metadata=res://*/UserManagementModel.csdl|res://*/UserManagementModel.ssdl|res://*/UserManagementModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx.xx.xx.xx;failover partner=yyyy.yy.yy.yy;initial catalog=testev;persist security info=True;user id=*********;password=********;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
     providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

We have only one database server, but the IP address of that server can change.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you have a primary connection and a backup (failover) connection, you can specify that in your connection string. If this is what you are looking for ?
Look at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/database-mirroring-in-sql-server

Comment: I have already added that as failover partner in connection string.(See my code above). It returns error **Cannot open connection** when the primary IP is down.